# ASP.NET MVC post model always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that I'm building and I cannot figure out why the model being posted back  is always null.

cshtml:

```
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TotalItemCategoryId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Label, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Label, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Label, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TotalTemplateId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllowDataEntry,new{@readonly="readonly"})
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsMiscellaneous) 
</div>
```

I have looked at the form and all of the fields are there with the correct values when posting. just when it gets to the controller it is always null. Can someone please help me figure this out.

Model class:

```
public class TotalItemValue:IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? TotalItemCategoryId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(125)]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
    public int QuoteId { get; set; }
    public int? TotalTemplateId { get; set; }

    public bool AllowDataEntry { get; set; }
    public bool IsMiscellaneous { get; set; }

    public TotalItemCategory TotalItemCategory { get; set; }
    public TotalTemplate TotalTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateMiscellaneousItem(int quoteId)
{
    TotalItemValue totalItemValue = _expressionTotalService.CreateMiscellaneousItem(quoteId);
    return View(totalItemValue);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateMiscellaneousItem( TotalItemValue value)
{
    _expressionTotalService.SaveMiscellaneousItem(value);

    return RedirectToAction("Totals", new{quoteId=value.QuoteId});
}
```

Comment: Can you show the **controller** code please.

Comment: Have you tried to add `[FromBody]` attribute for your model ?

Comment: There's no BeginForm() in your cshtml.  Is that just an oversight or is it really not there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Its null because your model contains a property named `value` and you have also named the parameter for your model `value` in the POST method.**

You must add `QuoteId` Property in `TotalItemValue` model and just change request parameter name from `value` to `model`.

Try This :

```
public class TotalItemValue:IEntity
{
      ...
      public int QuoteId{ get; set; }
      ...
}


[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateMiscellaneousItem(TotalItemValue model)
    {
       ...
       _expressionTotalService.SaveMiscellaneousItem(model);

       return RedirectToAction("Totals", new{model.QuoteId});
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TotalItemValue</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalItemCategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalItemCategoryId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalItemCategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Label, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Label, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Label, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuoteId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuoteId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalTemplateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalTemplateId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalTemplateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AllowDataEntry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AllowDataEntry)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AllowDataEntry, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsMiscellaneous, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsMiscellaneous)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsMiscellaneous, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: it is. `TotalItemValue value)`

Comment: I think the issue is you are passing in int quoteId and TotalItemValue value as the params for your Post, you need to change it to be just TotalItemValue, otherwise youll need to implement a custom model binder (i think) to do 2 params like that to your Post action. If you need quoteId, add it to your model which it looks like it is already there.

Comment: I do this in many different places in the application. This should work, quoteId is passed in from `url`

Comment: @JamTay317 Put quoteId in model.

Comment: I have changed to what you asked, its still null.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @JamTay317 I test it And work. just change request parameter name from `value` to `model` .

Comment: that did work, can you explain why?

Comment: @JamTay317 I think becuase in View Used with this name `model => model.`

Comment: thank you, i will remember this.

Comment: @Hossein that's incorrect. Please look at the duplicate so you understand what's actually wrong

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Right. Thanks for sharing